# ASP.NET Core email not sending without attachment - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: asp.net-core, smtp, email-attachments, mailkit

I am using below code if I upload attachment email is working but if there is no attachment email is not send bit its return 200 ok status.

This is my code

```
public async Task<ServicePostResponse> SendMailAsync(EmailRequest mailData) 
{ 
    var responce = new  ServicePostResponse(); 

    try 
    { 
        using (MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage()) 
        {
            MailboxAddress emailFrom = new MailboxAddress(_emailConfig.SenderName, _emailConfig.SenderEmail); 
            emailMessage.From.Add(emailFrom); 

            MailboxAddress emailTo = new MailboxAddress(mailData.EmailToName, mailData.EmailToId); 
            emailMessage.To.Add(emailTo); 

            emailMessage.Subject = mailData.EmailSubject;

            BodyBuilder emailBodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            emailBodyBuilder.TextBody = mailData.EmailBody;

            if (mailData.EmailAttachments != null && mailData.EmailAttachments.Any())
            {
                byte[] fileBytes;

                foreach (var attachment in mailData.EmailAttachments)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        attachment.CopyTo(ms);
                        fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    emailBodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(attachment.FileName, fileBytes, ContentType.Parse(attachment.ContentType));
                }
            }

            emailMessage.Body = emailBodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            using (SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await mailClient.ConnectAsync(_emailConfig.Server, _emailConfig.Port, false);
                await mailClient.AuthenticateAsync(_emailConfig.UserName,_emailConfig.Password);
                await mailClient.SendAsync(emailMessage);
                await mailClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }

        responce.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception Details
        responce.Success = false;
        responce.ErrorCode = ex.Message;

        return responce;
    }

    return responce;
}
```

I tried with attachment is working but without attachment not working.

Comment: i have added  emailBodyBuilder.HtmlBody = mailData.EmailBody; and its working now